# unity game crash after applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I build my project by unity 3.4.2 and run it in Xcode 4.2. The game quitted when executing the function UnityInitApplication(appPath).I can build and run other project correctly.I want to know the possible reasons.Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Comment: On behalf of @QamarZaman - Post the log here so that it could be analyzed the actual problem. For this Enable internal Profiler and copy the log.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the bundle identifier in unity and xcode are the same before building the app
2. If it dosent solve remove the app cache : Organizer -> Projects -> Select your app and delete and rebuild the project.